# How to use inner join in SqlCommandText in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use an `INNER JOIN` in my `SqlCommandText`, but when I try it, I get the error:

> "invalid column A.idCliente"

This select with `INNER JOIN` works fine in SQL Server.

```
sqlClient.Command.CommandText = 
    @"SELECT A.idCliente, A.DescCliente, A.DescAnalista, A.DataAtendimento,
             CL.Cliente, CL.Endereco 
      FROM Atendimento A 
      INNER JOIN Cliente CL ON CL.idCliente = A.idCliente";
sqlClient.ExecSQL();

ManutBLL objChamado = new ManutBLL();

if (sqlClient.Fill() > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow item in sqlClient.Table.Rows)
    {
        retorno.Chamados.Add(new ManutDTO
        {
            idCliente = UInt32.Parse(item["A.idCliente"].ToString()),
            Cliente = item["CL.Cliente"].ToString(),
            Endereco = item["CL.Endereco"].ToString(),
            DescAnalista = item["A.DescAnalista"].ToString(),
            DescCliente = item["A.DescCliente"].ToString(),
            DataAtendimento = Convert.ToDateTime(item["A.DataAtendimento"]),
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `item["A.idCliente"].ToString()` to `item["idCliente"].ToString()`

Comment: As @artm pointed out, the column names that return in your query are not prefixed with the table alias. You can check this by observing the column names in your Sql management tool and looking at the results. Remove the prefixes `A.` and `CL.` where you are parsing the results of the column.

Comment: it's works!  thanks a lot!